# .innerHTML doesn't work properly (I guess)

Tags: javascript, html

I use `.innerHTML` to add text in `textarea`. But If I starting edit text in `textarea` by myself script stops working.

Here it is:

```
(function($){
addPort = function(name) {
    switch(name) {
    case 'name1':
        var code = "text1"; 
        break
    case 'name2':
        var code = "text2";
        break
    case 'name3':
        var code = "text3";
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    document.getElementById("codeArea").innerHTML += code;
}; })(jQuery);
```

Don't pay attention on jQuery. Some other function use it.

Here's the `textarea`:

```
<textarea id="codeArea" name="codeAreaPost"></textarea>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its just replace `innerHTML` by value property

```
document.getElementById("codeArea").value
```

not `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` will parse the value as HTML and make the resulting DOM a child of your text area. This is not what you want. Try the `value` attribute instead:

```
document.getElementById("codeArea").value += code;
```